# Input value not passing to URL

Tags: javascript

I have a total of two input values. Only one value passes to the url of the next page, but both should. What's causing this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8dCC/

HTML:

```
  <!--form action="device" onSubmit=" get_search(); return false;" id="search-form-4" method="get" target="_top"-->
  <div class="fix">Brand</div>
  <input class="inputs" type="text" id="search_id" name="q3" placeholder="Send this" required="required" /> 
   <br/><br/>

  <div class="fix">Model</div>
  <input class="inputs" type="text" id="search_id" name="q4" placeholder="And send this one too" required="required" /> 
   <br/><br/>

<input id="search-button" class="" type="submit" value="continue" data-target="http://www.google.com/?item-description" />
<!--/form-->
```

Comment: Why is the form commented out?

Answer (score 2):

You have two elements with the same id in html. So when you do this `$('#search_id').val()` only one of them will get evaluated and not both. Ids are supposed to be unique

Comment: Even after giving the two inputs unique id's they still do not function as intended. http://jsfiddle.net/p8dCC/3/

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code in a test page, I found that both inputs were in fact being passed through the URL. 
You have commented out the form tags which I'm not sure if you did just for purposes on here.

kjs is correct as well, though using the same id would only effect the HTML. Using get as the method would bypass this issue as it would be passed the unique "name" attribute.

Comment: Even after giving the two inputs unique id's they still do not function as intended. http://jsfiddle.net/p8dCC/3/

Answer (score 0):

A form tag is required if you expect the html submission mechanism to work correctly on its own.

In the Javascript you posted though, you are treating document.location as an html element, wrapping it with jquery, then trying to use jquery's attr method on it. This won't work. Just access "location.href" directly without using jquery.

Additionally, as pointed out by another answer, your ids should all be unique.